# What does it mean to 'unlock' a VOIP adapter?

Tags: voip, sip

I'm thinking about buying VOIP adapter for home use. I already use SIP software on my PC and Mobile, but i think it would be easier to just pick up the phone at any time and call. And I could recycle old PSTN phone for that. The only thing I noticed is if I look for them on eBay, most of them are "unlocked" (like this one: [UNLOCKED Linksys SPA1001 one FXS VOIP PHONE ADAPTER for Asterisk Elastix Trixbox](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/UNLOCKED-linksys-SPA1001-one-FXS-VOIP-PHONE-ADAPTER-Asterisk-Elastix-Trixbox-/260999752648?pt=US_VoIP_Business_Phones_IP_PBX&hash=item3cc4cc2bc8#ht_5130wt_1165)).

I do not understand why. Isn't it that you just put your SIP provider proxy and password and it just should work? Why they were locked in the first time. When I google that, i find many sites that talk about unlocking them, but I'm not sure why they were locked in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I worked for a VoIP provider, we sold phones that were password protected and contained specific settings that were required for its use on our network. If I were to guess, this would be considered "locked" as the phone had details only to pull configs from our tftp servers and therefore could not be used anywhere else unless you had the password. I'd assume that the phones being sold on eBay have had the password cleared and are free to have any details configured into them for use on any network. Keep in mind that some VoIP providers will not let you use phones you have acquired this way, or they may just offer limited support - most want you to purchase their devices as that is how they make money. The VoIP provider I worked for allowed it, and would provide the config strings, but would not support the phone or its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

They are locked to the service provider who supplied you this box (In most cases, these are given out free as part of your subscription package and the intention is locking you to their services).

This is similar to our North American phone providers where they lock their phones with certain proprietary settings as they don't want you to use other SP Sim cards.

In conclusion, you will not have access to configure your SIP phone unless your adapter/voipbox is unlocked.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the accepted answer.